# Use the graph of $f$ to estimate the values of $c$ that satisfy the conclusion of the Mean Value Theorem for the interval $[0,8]$

Tags: calculus

This is my first post so please forgive me if I didn't post correctly. The question says to estimate the values of that satisfy the conclusion of the Mean Value Theorem based on this graph.

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXTB4.jpg)

I understand I have to draw a secant line that connects the points $\langle 0, 0\rangle$ and $\langle 8, 3\rangle$, then find the tangent lines, which I have estimated to be around $x=3.2$, $x=6.1$

I tried a few estimates and the answers were still wrong, so I was wondering if the math community can help me out.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: you need to add the function. To add a picture of some graph you can use the code `![my picture name](my picture URL)` between dollar signs.

Comment: Thanks Masacroso, but it says I don't have enough reps to post a pic. I posted a link to the image instead, is that okay?

Comment: Yes, it is ok, I cant change this situation either :(. Anyway it seems that your answer is ok... I think that there is a point between 2 and 3, and other between 6 or 7.